# Cloud Composer: How to Run A Single Task in a DAG Run via gcloud CLI

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to run a single task within a `DAG` on a `GCP` cloud composer airflow instance and mark all other tasks in the dag both upstream and downstream as successful. However, the following airflow command seems to not be working for me on cloud composer.

Does anyone know what is wrong with the following`gcloud cli` command?

```
dag_id: "airflow_monitoring" <br>
task_id: "echo1" <br>
execution_date: "2020-07-03" <br>


gcloud composer environments run my-composer --location us-centra1 \
-- "airflow_monitoring" "echo1" "2020-07-03"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you mark the test of the tasks as succeeded before running the task?

Answer (score 1):

If you aim just to correctly compose the above mentioned `gcloud` command, triggering the specific DAG, then after fixing some typos and propagating Airflow CLI sub-command parameters, I got this works:

```
gcloud composer environments run my-composer --location=us-central1 \
 --project=<project-id> trigger_dag -- airflow_monitoring --run_id=echo1 --exec_date="2020-07-03"
```

I would also encourage you to check out the full Airflow CLI sub-command [list](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#command-line-interface-reference).

In case you expect to get some different functional result, then feel free to expand the initial question, adding more essential content.